# eliminate space between tilde and letter in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

New bye here, I have a situation to solve, with two different behaviors of the tilde. The first looks normal, within a regular text, something like:

`... some text $\sim$A then some text ...`

but in equation mode (or even inside the equation dollar signs within the text), there is a space between the tilde and the letter (see the screenshot below):

`... some text $\sim{A}$ then some text ...`

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate that space, in equation mode?

I need it for equations mode:

`\[ \sim{A} = ... \]`

If relevant, in the preamble I use the package `lmodern` to use the CM10 font., plus some others dealing with equations: `mathptmx, amssymb, amsmath, mathspec` and parse the text with xelatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It is recommended to add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to every question. Such an MWE helps us to reproduce the problem, test our suggestions and give an answer (mostly also using a MWE).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default "math type" of `\sim` is `mathrel`, i.e., that of a relational operator. (Another example of an operator of type `mathrel` is `=`.) The default math type of the letter `A` is `mathord` ("math ordinary"). As you've "discovered", TeX automatically inserts some whitespace -- in the amount of `\thickmuskip` -- between elements of types `mathrel` and `mathord`, respectively.

If you do *not* wish to get whitespace between `\sim` and `A`, simply write

```
{\sim}A
```

This setup changes the math type of `\sim` to `mathord`, and TeX does *not* insert extra whitespace between elements of type `mathord`.

Answer (score 6):

Usually `\sim` is a relation like `=`. So the space is wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ A = B \]
\[ A \sim B \]
\end{document}
```

[image: \sim relation]

But you could also define it as an ordinary symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\mathchardef\simsym"0218
\begin{document}
\[ A \sim B \]
\[ A \simsym B \]
\end{document}
```

[image: sim ordinary]

For more information about math classes see, e.g., [TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html) section 38.3 and 23.3.

Instead of using `\mathchardef` you could also use

```
\newcommand*{\simsym}{\mathord\sim}
```

to define `\simsym` as the ordinary symbol variant of `\sim`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\simsym}{\mathord\sim}
\begin{document}
\[ A \sim B \]
\[ A \simsym B \]
\end{document}
```

The result is exactly the same as above and would be the same like with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\simsym}{{\sim}}% note the extra {…}
\begin{document}
\[ A \sim B \]
\[ A \simsym B \]
\end{document}
```